# How to integrate Azure Service Bus with Event Hub?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a scenario where the messages in the service bus topic has to be subscribed by a Event Hub. Can any one tell how to integrate Azure Service Bus and Event Hub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage Azure Logic app fro this.

You can use Service Bus trigger i n Logic app . Follow the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-servicebus

For Event Hub:

Follow the doc Monitor, receive, and send events with Azure Event Hubs and Azure Logic Apps
https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azure-event-hubs

Comment: I already tried the Logic app solution and it worked. Thanks for your response though.